# SQL Server 2008 varchar to decimal results in: "Error converting data type varchar to numeric"

Tags: sql-server, casting, decimal, numeric, varchar

I am trying to store a value stored as a varchar in a decimal field.

The following examples all results in: "Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

what am i missing here ?

```
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(11,2), '6.999,50') 
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(11, 2), '6.999,50')
SELECT CAST('6.999,50' AS decimal) / 100.0
SELECT CAST((CAST('6.999,50' AS decimal) / 100000) AS decimal(17,5))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the fact that 6.999,50 is not a valid decimal.  You can't have a comma and a decimal point in a decimal value surely?  What number is it supposed to be?

Assuming your locale specifies . as grouping and , as decimal separator:
To remove the grouping digits:

```
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(11,2), REPLACE('6.999,50', '.', ''))
```

will yield 6999,50 as a decimal

Comment: The result should be of format: decimal(11,2).

So i guess i need a function that filters the grouping digits ?

Comment: I've edited my answer with a replace example to remove the '.' character.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that its your locale settings. Your locale uses comma as a decimal point and period as a seperator. You sql server is probably set up as the default US English which is the other way around, period as decimal point, comma as a seperator.

Comment: regardless of locale I don't think SQL will cope converting varchar containing grouping characters.